# How to pull out the rows based on two conditions on columns

Tags: python, date, dataset, conditional-statements, max

I would like to create a new dataset from the current dataset (attached as a photo below) that take the unique `loanId` but with the most recent `ListingEventDate` and all the other columns.

I tried a few codes such as

```py
df.groupby(['LoanNumber'])['listingEventDate'].transform('max')
```

and

```py
group = df.groupby('LoanNumber')['listingEventDate'].max()
a = df[df['LoanNumber'].isin(group[group].index)]
```

but it does not work. I would appreciate any solution.

[image]